# How to enforce and inject strategies in child classes

Tags: python

Can someone help me understand if there is a better way to enforce inject strategy (from list of common strategies) in the child classes. Please find the example code below.

I am not fully convinced of wrapping these strategies as static methods and providing value of strategy as None in the base class. This is because there is no strategy injection enforcement happening here and it does not look natural/obvious to solve this problem using inheritance.

Can I achieve this in some better way?

```
def strategy1():
    print("strategy1")

def strategy2():
    print("strategy2")

class Base():
    strategy = None

class Child1(Base):
    strategy = staticmethod(strategy1)

class Child2(Base):
    strategy = staticmethod(strategy2)

class Child3(Base):
    strategy = staticmethod(strategy1)

Child1.strategy()
Child2.strategy()
Child3.strategy()
```

My main requirements are

1. Code (strategy) reuse across inheritance hierarchy
2. Enforce child classes to inject these strategies when they override base class.

Comment: How is inheritance not a natural/obvious way of solving a problem formulated in terms of child classes?  And it doesn't look like you are injecting anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might instead use a strategy class which you inject the strategy functions into:

```
import abc

def strategy1(self):
    print("strategy1")

class AbstractClient(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def execute(self):
        pass

class StrategizedClient(AbstractClient):
    execute = strategy1

class PlanlessClient(AbstractClient):
    pass
```

This requires python3, but it will enforce that your child classes inject a strategy:

```
>>> StrategizedClient()
<strategy.StrategizedClient object at 0x10fd594a8>
>>> PlanlessClient()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class PlanlessClient with abstract methods execute
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I guess you got the problem a bit wrong. Here classes (base and child) are not representing strategies rather they want to use some strategy. That is why there is composition of strategy in these classes. A base class can define which strategy it will be using by default and child classes can override the strategy they want to use.

Comment: strategy1(self), passing this self to a function not a part of class looks weird.

Comment: agreed. there is no tailored solution in the python standard library for this that i know of. If you really want to make it look a bit more standard, you might consider using a function decorator that checks that the function is bound to a class so that no callers try to call the function on its own, and use a leading underscore. You may also avoid the "self" keyword, and use "object". Also it is not necessary to use a standard method, it can also be an abstract staticmethod. Just add `@staticmethod` above the `@abc.abstractmethod` decorator.

Comment: Annotating with staticmethod as well as abc.abstractmethod makes sense I guess. Thanks